# sbatch pass exit codes of dependent jobs

Tags: dependencies, slurm, sbatch

I have some jobs started with sbatch, e.g.

```
a=$(sbatch ...)
b=$(sbatch ...)
```

Now a third job is queued after a or b are done:

```
c=$(sbatch --dependency=afterany:$a:$b ...)
```

How can I pass the exit status of task a and b to the script of c?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options;

- have `c` read a file on disk, that is produced by `a` and `b`;
- have `c` use `sacct` to retrieve the status of `a` and `b`:

  sacct -X -n -o state -j $a

Comment: Using `sacct -o -n -o state -j <jobid>` I get the error `sacct: error: Invalid field requested: "-n"`. If I use `sacct -o state -j <jobid>` I get meaningful output, but for some jobs I get duplicated output, e.g. `State\n----------\n RUNNING\n RUNNING`. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: because `sacct` will output one line for the job and as many subsequent lines as there are job steps. Us `-X` to have only one line.